# SQL query to return object along with related objects

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have this line that maps a SQL query to a model in C#

```
var local = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Dealer>(selectQuery).ToList();
```

The problem is that  also has some ICollections of related objects, that are diffrent tables in my DB. Is it possible to modify my SQL query to return those relations, and store them in the dealer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteStoreQuery` won't populated related objects. You would need to have a Linq query where you could use `.Include` to load related entities eagerly.

Btw. you can execute Sql query directly from DbContext by using DbContext.Database.SqlQuery (no need to drop down to the ObjectContext).

Comment: Thanks. The reason that im not using Linq is because I need to use FullText search capabilities not supported by linq.

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to load related entities separately (they actually should be loaded automatically if you try accessing them and lazy loading is enabled).